# Optimizing CSS/JS imports for Static website using common a JS document

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

Coming from a server side programming background, this might be a noob question.

Currently I have css laid out like below and also JS in a similar fashion.

```
<link type ="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link type="text/css" href="css/custom.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link type="text/css" href="css/template.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

But I have around some 40-50 html pages remaining to be coded and dropped in and all pages share the same CSS/JS more or less.So, how do I avoid this boilerplate typing.Can I just do like below

```
var navBar = ['<div class="hi-icon-wrap hi-icon-effect-9 hi-icon-effect-9a" text-align="">',
                        '<a class="hi-icon hi-icon-fa-home" style="text-decoration:none!important" href="index" title="Blah"></a>Home',
                        '<a class="hi-icon hi-icon-fa-wrench" style="text-decoration:none!important" href="tools" title="Blah"></a>Tools',
                        '<a class="hi-icon hi-icon-fa-folder-o" style="text-decoration:none!important"href="blog" title="Blah"></a>Blog',
                        '<a class="hi-icon hi-icon-fa-user" style="text-decoration:none!important" href="about" title="Blah"></a>About Me',
                    '</div>'].join('\n')
```

I mean using the same logic to print out `<script>` and `<link>` tags?If so, does it have any disadvantages or is there a better way to do it.

Comment: If you are open to using a build process like [Grunt](http://gruntjs.com) or [Gulp](http://gulpjs.com/), you could concatenate all the CSS into one file, and all your Javascript into one file and then just reference those two files everywhere. Just regenerate the combined files after you make a change.

Comment: @GregL : Yes,I am open to anything open source.How do I do that ? Do you have any example or anything just to get me started in that direction, I am using Jekyll to build BTW.Thanks for helping :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using Jekyll, you should just use the [Includes feature](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/templates/#includes) built in.

All you do is have a `_includes` folder in the root folder of your project, and add a `js-css.html` file in there with all your `<script>` and `<link>` tags to reference the JS and CSS files.

Then in your template, you would just have:

```
{% include js-css.html %}
```

in your `<head>` tag everywhere.

Comment: Thanks for that.But it is just throwing up the content without parsing it.Then I found this : http://nateeagle.com/2011/08/31/jekyll-not-parsing-includes/. Let me get back after doing some debugging

Comment: What content are you referring to? Is what is in the `js-css.html` file just some HTML `<script src="..."></script>` and `<link type="text/css" href="..." rel="stylesheet">` tags?

Comment: Here is what I did. 1) Put all script,link tags in the js-css.html file inside the _includes folder 2) Using {% include js-css.html %} in head section of my html files to include 3) Did jekyll serve.And the includes is just printed out like HTML i.e it is not getting parsed.What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: I am not using any jekyll templates.Just using it for disqus and 404 error pages so far.I use a direct HTML template to write content and not markdow,not sure how that will fit in here.

Comment: I haven't used Jekyll myself, sorry. But [this page](http://wolfslittlestore.be/2012/08/html-includes-with-jekyll/) looks promising.

Comment: Somehow banging my head to get this done.Jekyll does not seem to pick when I use {% include filename.extension %}.It is just printed as text.It is a bad day I guess.